# How can I change data-value in bootstrap editable element after it's changed?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I'm using the bootstrap editable plugin to allow users to edit fields on the screen. One of the fields, when clicked, displays a small popup that lets users select from a dropdown with a checkmark next to the dropdown to allow the user to apply the value to the field. My markup has a simple anchor that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" id="primaryoption_1" data-type="select" data-name="option" data-value="0" class="editable-discreet">Split EM/SEM</a>
```

My jQuery code has this to enable this feature using bootstrap:

```
 var gaPrimaryOptions = [
    { value: 0, text: 'Split EM/SEM' },
    { value: 1, text: 'Only EM' },
    { value: 2, text: 'Only SEM' }
    ];

$("a[id^=primaryoption_][id!='primaryoption_{departmentid}']").editable({
        source: gaPrimaryOptions,
        onblur: 'submit'
    });
```

If you notice my markup has a data-value attribute with a default value of "0".

The problem I'm having is how to change the data-value to the appropriate value when a user selects another item from the dropdown list and clicks the checkmark. My data-value always stays to "0" even when the user selects another item like "Only EM" which has a value of "1".

Comment: Did you try something like:  `$("#primaryoption_1").attr("data-value", 2 );` already?

Comment: That's the line that will set the value but I have to put that line in some sort of event or function call. Where do I do that with x-editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you checking the value, using the dev tools in the browser? If so, I don't think you'll see the value changing like you want it to.

Reason for asking is because the code seems fine, try this:

```
var gaPrimaryOptions = [
    { value: 0, text: 'Split EM/SEM' },
    { value: 1, text: 'Only EM' },
    { value: 2, text: 'Only SEM' }
];


$("a[id^=primaryoption_][id!='primaryoption_{departmentid}']").editable({
    source: gaPrimaryOptions,
    onblur: 'submit',
    validate: function(value) {
        console.log("You've chosen " + value);
    }, success: function(response, newValue) {
        console.log("New value is " + newValue);
    }
});

current_value = $("a[id^=primaryoption_][id!='primaryoption_{departmentid}']").editable('getValue', true);
console.log("Curent value is " + current_value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3KkZd/375/

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was looking for, the validate and success evants. Didn't know the plugin had them. I basically took the new value and set the data-value in the success code.

Comment: I've been using this plugin a lot the past couple of days so I understand your pain, it can quite restricting for complex things but the docs help, you can find them here http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html